# protecting admins controller with password

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to protect my admins controller with a password. I added this:

```
  before_filter :authenticate

  protected
  def authenticate
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
      username == "user" && password == "pass!"
    end
  end
```

Into admins_controller.rb but when I visit any admins route like `/admins` or `/admins/sign_in` or `admins/sign_up`, no dialog shows up for the user to input the credentials.

I used this before for protecting the whole page by placing it at application_controller.rb; exactly the same way I use it now, and it worked fine before.

Any clue what might be wrong? (p.s. I use devise)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected
def authenticate
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic_with name: "user", password: "pass!"
end
```